# CS50 Tideman program works perfectly but check50 says otherwise

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, cs50, adjacency-matrix

I enrolled in Harvard's CS50 introductory course and am stuck in a certain assignment (to finish the code of a tideman election simulation), and before submitting the assignment, it is possible to check the correctness of your code by running check50 in Harvard's CS50 IDE

based on multiple tests I've run, my program works perfectly, but every time I run check50 it returns an error saying:

- :( lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle

  - Cause: lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs

edit: full details into how the program is supposed to work is in this link https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/3/tideman/

I have tried multiple tests, from simple ones (three candidates with 5 votes) to more complex ones (four candidates and 9 votes that create a small middle cycle and a last cycle) and my code works fine and properly.

If anyone could find what the wrong in my code's logic, and maybe even possibly a way to shorten my code would be highly appreciated because in my opinion it looks pretty messy XD

My main problem lies within this lock_pairs() function

```
// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO

    //initialize an array that could tell whether a pair used to be locked or not
    bool wasLocked[MAX][MAX];

    //clear the wasLocked array
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
        {
            wasLocked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    //loop through each pair
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        //temporarily set current pair to true on locked array
        locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;

        //permanently set current pair to true on wasLocked array
        wasLocked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;

        //pointee is the loser in the current pair
        int pointee = pairs[i].loser;
        bool checkCycle = true;

        while (checkCycle == true)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pair_count; j++)
            {
                //if the current pointee is one of the winners
                if (pointee == pairs[j].winner)
                {
                    //if the pointee and pointee's loser pair is not locked in
                    if (locked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] == false)
                    {
                        //And if the pointee and pointee's loser pair was never locked in in the first place
                        if (wasLocked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] == false)
                        {
                            checkCycle = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        //else skip this pair and restart the cycle looking for another pointee winner
                    }

                    //if the pointee and pointee's loser pair is already locked in
                    else if (locked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] == true)
                    {
                        //if it does create a cycle, don't lock in the current winning pair
                        if (pairs[j].loser == pairs[i].winner)
                        {
                            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = false;
                            checkCycle = false;
                            break;
                        }

                        //if not sure if it creates a cycle, follow the path of pointees until we get to a cycle or not
                        else
                        {
                            pointee = pairs[j].loser;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //if the pointee is not one of the winners and we have reached the end of the loop without breaking
                //break out of checkCycle loop to officially lock in the winning pair
                else if (j == pair_count - 1)
                {
                    checkCycle = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Here's the full code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);
            vote(j, name, ranks);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
//note: this function is called depending on the amount of candidates and the array of ranks change per voter
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    // TODO

    //loops through candidates
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        //once we find the corresponding candidate given the name, then we put the index of that candidate into the chosen rank of
        //the current voter
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i]) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    // TODO

    //basically this will update preferences wherein the highest rank will dominate in votes over the lower ranks
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]]++;
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] > 0)
            {
                //check for ties, if ties are found then skip
                if (preferences[i][j] != preferences[j][i])
                {
                    //check for a winning pair, then add to pair array
                    if (preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
                    {
                        pairs[pair_count].winner = i;
                        pairs[pair_count].loser = j;
                        pair_count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO

    //set the index for where the greatest value would be placed if found
    int index = 0;

    bool is_sorted = false;
    while (is_sorted == false)
    {
        for (int i = index; i < pair_count; i++)
        {
            //this makes it so that when we detect an increase of index, we restart the loop to find the next greatest value
            int indexPast = index;

            //set 'a' to be the current greatest value to compare
            int a = preferences[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser];

            for (int j = i + 1; j < pair_count; j++)
            {
                //preference 'b' would be compared to 'a'
                int b = preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser];

                //if 'a' has made it through the loop without breaking
                if (j == pair_count - 1)
                {
                    if (a < b)
                    {
                        pair temp = pairs[index];
                        pairs[index] = pairs[j];
                        pairs[j] = temp;
                        index++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (a >= b)
                    {
                        pair temp = pairs[index];
                        pairs[index] = pairs[i];
                        pairs[i] = temp;
                        index++;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //'b' is greater than 'a', compare the next value with 'b' being our current greatest value
                else if (a < b)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            //if we have noticed a change in index, restart the whole while loop to find the next greatest value
            if (index > indexPast)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        //if 'a' is the last value in the array and the loop hasnt been broken, the array is now sorted with 'a' being the lowest value
        if (index >= pair_count - 1)
        {
            is_sorted = true;
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO

    //initialize an array that could tell whether a pair used to be locked or not
    bool wasLocked[MAX][MAX];

    //clear the wasLocked array
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
        {
            wasLocked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    //loop through each pair
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        //temporarily set current pair to true on locked array
        locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;

        //permanently set current pair to true on wasLocked array
        wasLocked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;

        //pointee is the loser in the current pair
        int pointee = pairs[i].loser;
        bool checkCycle = true;

        while (checkCycle == true)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pair_count; j++)
            {
                //if the current pointee is one of the winners
                if (pointee == pairs[j].winner)
                {
                    //if the pointee and pointee's loser pair is not locked in
                    if (locked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] == false)
                    {
                        //And if the pointee and pointee's loser pair was never locked in in the first place
                        if (wasLocked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] == false)
                        {
                            checkCycle = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        //else skip this pair and restart the cycle looking for another pointee winner
                    }

                    //if the pointee and pointee's loser pair is already locked in
                    else if (locked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] == true)
                    {
                        //if it does create a cycle, don't lock in the current winning pair
                        if (pairs[j].loser == pairs[i].winner)
                        {
                            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = false;
                            checkCycle = false;
                            break;
                        }

                        //if not sure if it creates a cycle, follow the path of pointees until we get to a cycle or not
                        else
                        {
                            pointee = pairs[j].loser;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //if the pointee is not one of the winners and we have reached the end of the loop without breaking
                //break out of checkCycle loop to officially lock in the winning pair
                else if (j == pair_count - 1)
                {
                    checkCycle = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO

    //we loop through the locked array to find a candidate that was never locked in as a loser
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (locked[j][i] == true)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (j == candidate_count - 1)
            {
                //a winning candidate was found and was never locked in as a loser
                if (locked[j][i] == false)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Please feel free to run my code and try any other checks that may break my code because I do not know what to do anymore XD

Tips to make my code a little bit more efficient are highly appreciated as well :)

edit:

my print_winner() function used to have errors but I was able to fix it by changing pair_count to candidate_count after reviewing a similar question posted by @EthanMark

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you mind telling us what your code is supposed to do? Do you have more details about the failing test?

Comment: oh my bad, totally forgot about details

Comment: `locked[i][j] = false;` With `locked` being a global variable with static duration, it is automatically initialized to 0. You can skip those loops.

Comment: `vote(j, name, ranks); if (!vote(j, name, ranks))` You know that you call the function twice, don't you?

Comment: alright, thanks Gerhardh noted :)

Comment: actually those things you have pointed out were already in harvard's code. All I had to do was complete the functions other than int main()

Comment: my real problem is lock_pairs()

Comment: On the other side, `int ranks[candidate_count];` is a local variable which is not initialized automatically. You might want to reset in each iteration of your loop.

Comment: Oh, OK. Will skip those improvements

Comment: Please, check this post and my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64155643/cs50-tideman-lock-paiors-function-issue?r=SearchResults. I think it will help